# my mock junit5 is not working with my subclass

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

i have a system that uses other system and im trying to test it but i dont want to call the external system all the time.

```
my system -> my http url -> inside the code i call external system
                                           |
  output <- process response <------------
```

ideally i want to fake / mock the data so i dont need to call external system

my code

```
class MMarket {
 @GetController("/stock/{stock}"
 public String loadStockFromYahoo(@PathVariable("stock") String stock) {
   LoadStock stockObject = new LoadStock();
   String result = stockObject.getYahoo(stock);
   return result;
 }

}
```

my class i want to mock

```
class LoadStock{

...
  public String getYahoo(String stock) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject("my url with + stock", String.class);
    return result;
  }
}
```

in my test i do:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) //junit5
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
class MMarketTest {



    @Autowired MMarket mMarket;

    @Mock LoadStock loadStock;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(loadStock.getYahoo(any())).thenReturn("123");
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {

        String result = mMarket.loadStockFromYahoo("mystock");
    }

}
```

the "   String result" is the result from the restTemplate.getForObject call NOT my mock
which if i want to test multiple time it will call the external system which i do not want

Comment: The mock is not  used since the code under test is creating a new instance of `LoadStock`.  `LoadStock` needs to be injected into `MMarket` through a constructor (or @Autowired).  This will allow the unit test to inject the mock.

Comment: I tried, "MMarket(LoadStock loadStock) { ..." and same result

Comment: Can you use PowerMocktio?

Comment: @am0awad I can, but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMocktio to the initialize and pass your mocked LoadStock

```
@PrepareForTest(MMarket.class)
@RunWith(PowerMocktio.class)
class MMarketTest {

    private MMarket mMarket;

    @Mock LoadStock loadStock; // will be injected to MMarket

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(loadStock.getYahoo(any())).thenReturn("123");
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
     PowerMockito.whenNew(LoadStock.class).withNoArguments()
     .thenReturn(mockedLoadStock);
        String result = mMarket.loadStockFromYahoo("mystock");
    }
}
```

, If you can not use PowerMocktio, you can autowire LoadStock and in the test use `@InjectMocks`

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
class MMarketTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    MMarket mMarket;

    @Mock LoadStock loadStock; // will be injected to MMarket

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(loadStock.getYahoo(any())).thenReturn("123");
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        String result = mMarket.loadStockFromYahoo("mystock");
    }
}
```

Comment: same error: ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "1.1.1.1:1111" failed: connect timed out

Comment: @yenk Did you `@autowire` LoadStock in `MMarket` class?

Comment: Yes the LoadStock is in the constructor @Autowired

Comment: Strange! you can check PowerMocktio solution

Comment: RunWith does NOT WORK with JUnit 5/Jupiter.